# jQuery click() not working. Really don't understand

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, click, web2py

I have a html with python to dynamically load some buttons defined in a css:

```
<div id="Menu">
<center>
{{for nickname, my_id in zip(nicknames, my_ids):}}
<myButton class="c" name="{{=nickname}}", value={{=nickname}} id="{{=my_id}}">{{=nickname}}</myButton>
{{pass}}
</center>
</div>
```

then I have some javascript below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".c").click(function() {
            alert("haha");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Clicking on the buttons just doesn't work. I have viewed many threads here but I cannot find what the problem I get here. Browser is Chrome.

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery? Any error?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem is a syntax error.

Comment: Learn [how to](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) to be able to find the problem yourself.

Comment: @maketest: Why on earth did you "fix" the code? That was the OP's problem. If you want to *answer* the question then do so, but don't edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to close those functions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".c").click(function() {
        alert("haha");
    });
});
```